# Bridging a Modem with a Static IP from an ISP

Tags: router, port-forwarding, linux-server, fedora-19

I have setup a headless linux server running: 22, 80, 1194 (udp) and it's also running a DHCP server and does all of the ip assigning.

Starting off, I was simply trying to port forward all incoming requests to my server.

Internally of course, I can connect to all my ports and everything works well. Externally the only ports that were showing open were 80 and 8080 and they both timeout.

After researching, the answer for similar scenarios was to bridge the modem.

My ISP, Roadrunner claimed at first the only way to bridge was to have a static ip. They said with the modem we had was restricted and wasn't allowed to be bridged.

So I got a static IP installed. $45 to install and $10 a month.

I setup the router with the new static, re-setup port forwarding; however, using the static IP still didn't work.

So I called my ISP and ended up spending 7 hours trying to get this to work. I talked to at least 5 people in all; some said that you can't bridge at all and had no clue of what I was talking about.

I have an ubee modem, and after finding the actualy hard link in the GUI -> 192.168.1.100/TImodechange.asp howver this is inaccessible to the customer. So finally I got a rep to do this for me. The issue was that after it was done I received my old dynamic IP and the internet would only stay active for 2 minutes before booting the router offline. Called back and the next rep told him what was done and said looks like a bug in the last script. He got the modem rescripted and I was back to where I started.

So called again...

Finally the last person told me that you can't bridge a static ip. He said if you bridge the modem you will get a dynamic IP. And that sounded about right, because that is basically what happened when one of the reps did actually bridge it for me. I had to stop at this point.

After reading into it, my solution seems to be that I have to make the *Ubee Modem* act as a modem only passing all of the traffic to the router which does the port forwarding.

**1.** Can you not bridge with a Static Ip?

**2.** Without bridging how can this be done?

Comment: Too many question pop into my head. Here are a couple... What is the type of the Ubee? Do you have a router behind the Ubee? If not are you using the other ports or do you have a switch? Why not use the DHCP of the Ubee? But either way, (1) static or dynamic ip shouldn't matter for bridging. In bridging mode the first device behind the Ubee will get the public ip. (2) Without bridging you should be able to use port-forwarding. So you should find out why this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Why do you want to bridge the modem? Isnt't it easier and better to bridge the NIC that receives the public IP from the modem (because you have control on it...) or are you pluging the modem diretly into a router? If that's the case, I think better to plug it in the machine that runs the headless server and share internet from there.

Comment: After reading your responses, it's triggered some ideas I'm going to try out. I'll return with some answers. Thanks @laurent